# design headache with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, factory, unique-ptr

Say we have class `Foo`:

```
class Foo {
public:
  ...
};
```

`Foo` has an instance method which either transforms the `Foo` instance into another `Foo` instance, or returns the same `Foo` instance:

```
<some appropriate pointer type to Foo> Foo::tryToTransform() {
  if (canBeTransformed()) {
    <delete this Foo instance>;
    return <new instance of Foo>;
  }
  else {
    return <this instance of Foo>;
  }
}
```

Client code:

```
<some appropriate pointer type to Foo> foo = ...;
...
foo = foo->tryToTransform();
```

This is easy to do with naked pointers:

```
Foo* Foo::tryToTransform() {
  if (canBeTransformed()) {
    delete this;
    return new Foo(...);
  }
  else {
    return this;
  }
}

Foo* foo = ...;
...
foo = foo->tryToTransform();
```

But what if the client code uses a `unique_ptr` instead of a naked pointer? That is, ideally I would like the client code to look like this:

```
unique_ptr<Foo> foo = ...;
...
foo = foo->tryToTransform();
```

How should `Foo::tryToTransform()` be defined in order to enable such (or similar) client code?

Comment: Aiee! `delete this` is a **terrible** idea. Make your transform method a static method and all your woes will disappear.

Comment: Moreover i see this applicable only if you want to *change* object *type*, i.e. transform instance of `X` to instance of `Y`. Otherwise, why would you delete and recreate object?

Comment: @nneonneo 1. I am not a fan of `delete this`, but it's OK in some circumstances - see, for example, [this FAQ article](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-this) 2. How would making `Foo::tryToTransform()` static help the `unique_ptr` issue in any way?

Comment: @el.pescado The point is that `tryToTransform()`, when is can transform the `Foo` instance, transforms it into another instance **which has different state**. (Class `Foo` does have state, although I did not show it explicitly in the contrived code snippet.)

Comment: You can force object to different state without having to allocate new instance of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your `tryToTransform` function is a *member function*, the caller retains ownership of the `unique_ptr`. It is therefore *impossible* (without dirty tricks) to delete a caller's `unique_ptr` from inside the member function.

Therefore, you *need* a static function that takes ownership of the `unique_ptr`:

```
class Foo {
    static unique_ptr<Foo> tryToTransform(unique_ptr<Foo> ptr) {
        if(...) {
            return unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo()); // old ptr is destroyed
        } else {
            return ptr;
    }
};
```

Call as

```
unique_ptr<Foo> foo = ...;
...
foo = Foo::tryToTransform(move(foo));
```

This works by having `tryToTransform` take ownership of the `unique_ptr`. It is then able to destroy the pointer as it wishes.